# Static keyword workaround for "out of memory" error?

Tags: static, vb6

**Is there some known VB6 problem or issue for which using a static variable could avoid an out of memory error?**

---

Details:

Got a unique end user problem report which described an error #7 "out of memory" from the VB6 application I support. This is the only case of the problem that I know of; I have not been able to reproduce it locally.

The error report indicated the procedure which failed; in that proc I found the following:

```
'the below is static because it didn't fit on the stack
Static obReport As clsReport

'this makes it work like it did when it was on the stack
Set obReport = Nothing
Set obReport = New clsReport
```

Maybe someone in years past had a similar error and came up with this hack as a workaround. We don't have this pattern anywhere else that I have seen.

---

As far as I can tell the reported "out of memory" error does not occur until later in the code long after these lines here have been executed.

---

The (ancient) [documentation reference for this error message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264522%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) doesn't seem to offer anything corresponding to this. Google/SO searching didn't turn anything up either.

---

My interpretation is that the author was trying to free up stack space by allocating the `obReport` variable to the heap by making it `Static`. I can imagine someone thinking this could "save" on memory somehow.

But this snippet may just be nonsense... if anything the `Static` keyword only gets the object **reference** off the stack, not the actual object which I think would be in the heap anyway. I can't see how this could have resolved any problems **unless it is a VB6 quirk/bug which just can't be reasoned about normally.**

(Or, I'm just wrong - enlighten me!)

Comment: `Dim obReport As clsReport` takes 4 *bytes* of stack. The comment can have any relevance if the function is called recursively.

Comment: @wqw good point and a good thing to check; but no it is not recursive. And I doubt it once was but no longer is. The procedure's job is to gather data then show some reports.

Comment: If you were out of stack, I think you would be getting an `Out of stack space` error. I think thx is on the right track with the user somehow exhausting memory, either by triggering a memory leak in the program, or using up system resources.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the ancient versions of VB, even back into VBDOS, had some quirks like you describe but I don’t think they were related to classes. We used to call the solutions “programming  by witchcraft” and they typically were used to trigger garbage collection. The instructions themselves didn’t do anything at all but their presence would cause garbage collection to occur at difference locations in the code. The giveaway was usually “DO NOT MOVE OR REMOVE THE BELOW CODE”.

I do see some things that, when viewed from a larger perspective, might lead to a solution. “unique end user problem” and “This is the only case of the problem that I know of; I have not been able to reproduce it locally” and “the reported ‘out of memory’ error does not occur until later in the code”. And from VBA documentation you linked: “You have too many applications, documents, or source files open. Close any unnecessary applications, documents, or source files that are open.” The only “out of memory” or “out of resources” I have seen like this occurred on machines where the end user had many, many programs and/or browsers or browser windows open when running with a very small amount of RAM.

So examine the end user’s run time environment using Remote Desktop or some such while the error is displayed. It may be a valid error message.

From VBA documentation you linked:  “You have a module or procedure that's too large. Break large modules or procedures into smaller ones. This doesn't save memory, but it can prevent hitting 64K segment boundaries.” Have you tried this? It would be the next step.

You may just have a memory leak. Check for this using Task Manager to see if you have multiple instances of obReport created and not being terminated properly. "The procedure's job is to gather data then show some reports." How much data and how many reports? Could it be a problem trying to handle a huge amount of data either by design or programming error that is causing the out of memory error?